PL/SQL Function Body Returning SQL Query
I want to do 1 simple type of development in Oracle APEX such as, I am having a select list in the top and will be having report on the down side, the select list will show the list of some table names. On the click of that, my report should show the selected table's data. In the report I am using PL/SQL function body returning SQL Query as the source of the report. In my package, I have a function, which will return the query to show the data for the selected table. Like example, for selected value as ‘EMP’ it returns select * from EMP
But in the source of interactive report, I did something like this:
    declare
      v_result varchar2(4000);
    begin
      v_result := EBA_DEMO_CARD_PKG.show_data(:P50_TNAME);
     return v_result;
    end

Here, ofc you will get to know what is package name, function name, page item name and returning variable. So i externally also cross checked by executing the function body, and it does return query value like select * from EMP , so as per APEX its getting a PL/SQL Function body returning SQL Query, but still its not accepting this. It still says

ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH


I am not getting what to do, or do we have any other alternative solution which will let me select the table name from the select list and then the report will show the corresponding table's data?
I want to retrieve table's data based on the select list selection

Are you 100% sure that the query is correct ? First thing to do is to verify if that is the case by debugging your code.  Change the page process to
declare
  v_result varchar2(4000);
begin
  v_result := EBA_DEMO_CARD_PKG.show_data(:P50_TNAME);
  apex_debug.info(
    p_message => q'#debug query: %0#',
    p0        => :P10_SLOT_BOOKING_ID);
  return v_result;
end;

Then run the page in debug mode and look for the entry containing the string "debug query".
One thing to note is that you mention an interactive report in your post. Note that an interactive report only supports a fixed number of columns at compile time. So you need to ensure that your function returns a fixed number of columns or use a classic report instead.
Another thing is that this is NOT "1 simple type of development". APEX reports assume that the query is know at design time. Creating a page with a dynamic query is possible, but not a trivial task in APEX

Hello @Koen Lostrie , I got an issue while debugging, its that, the value from the select list was not being passed to the report query. I am still facing the same issue. Please anyone suggest me the property changes to the select list/report if any required. or any dynamic action required. When i manually enter the table name in the report query to pass to the function then i am getting the proper output, but not when passed the select list page item,

Do you have the page item set in the "items to submit" attribute of the report ?

Yes, under the report, I added the select list's page item to set as submit page item. Additionally, I moved my devt to APEX 22.2, and made some general changes, and now i am able to use the interactive grid to view tables dynamically. there are some challenges still present like the col names, data types, and count need to be same for all the tables which we will be showing
